# Fiware Orion Context Broker-Send notifications after a period of time

Tags: publish-subscribe, fiware, fiware-orion, fiware-perseo

I want to create a subscription for an entity and to be notified by context broker after a change of measure after a specific time.

For example if  humidity reaches a threshold i don't want to be notified.

But if humidity measurement is changed and reaches or is uppon a threshold for 5 days continuously then i would like to be notified.

Is there any pattern for Orion Context Broker Subscriptions for such a purpose?

Essentially, i would like to avoid being notified after some peaks of a measurement .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Orion is <strike>mainly stateless</strike> focused in *current* context and doesn't keep a *history* of the context, so it can be difficult to set conditions on "time windows" like the one I understand you describe.

However, the FIWARE ecosystem provides components (GEs in FIWARE parlance) that can do that work and interoperate with Orion. In particular, the [Perseo Complex Event Processor](https://github.com/telefonicaid/perseo-fe) can connect to Orion as notifications receiver and trigger rules based on time window conditions.

How to configure and use Perseo is out of the scope of this answer but in the above link you will find information about the component, documentation and examples.

Comment: Thank you Sir for your answer! I will check this out!